# How to hide custome options in product detail page if not available

Tags: custom-options, products, custom-attributes

I have a supplement store that will have about 6ooo plus products but mainly because there are products with different weight that needs to be inserted one by one. I can do one product with custom options for the weight and here comes my problem.

Example:
Jumbo protein comes in 2860G, 4400G and 8800G.
There are 4 flavors, Chocolate, Vanilla, Strawberry, and coconut
All 4 flavors are available to the Jumbo 2860g and jumbo 4400G but Coconut flavour isn't available to jumbo 8800G.
How can I hide this coconut flavour when the client chooses Jumbo 8800G, and show it again if client chooses the other weights?
Basically how can I hide a custom option if not available?
As you can imagine if i get this to work it will save me tons of work and reduces my store from 6000 plus products to half.

Im using magento CE 1.8.1.0

Comment: Is it a Magento 2 store?

Answer (score 0):

You would of course create a configurable product based on the attributes 'weight' and 'flavour'.
The configurable product will have the 11 related productes. Coconut 8800 will not exist, so if the client applies the first filter in the configurable product, for example 'Coconut', then for the second filter automatically only 2860G and 4400G will be visible.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that will work Marcel.
The attribute Flavour is easy, about 60 types of flavour for the options, but for the attribute (weight) will have options from 1g up to 12.000g since I gave you just one product example, I have proteins, creatine and all products based on powder from 50g up. Imagine making all this on a attribute.